# setText deprecated

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

i saw your comment about getting rid of the setText deprecated error, and using cell.textLabel.text it works perfectly for OS 4.0 but it doesn't work on 3.1.3, the app crashes at the loading screen, have you got any ideas?

Comment: stackoverflow missed connections

Answer (score 0):

`.textLabel.text` certainly works in 3.x — it's *introduced* in 3.x! But make sure the app you're running was compiled from a 3.x SDK.

Try to switch to the 3.1.3 SDK, and Build and Run.